# OpenCv detectMultiScale scale search algorithm

Tags: opencv, face-detection

I was wondering if `OpenCV`in case of `haar` features and `lbp` scales the image during the multiscale search or it scales the features itself as it mentioned in a paper?

**EDIT:** As it turns out the detector scales images, not features. Does anybody know why? It can be much faster with scaling the features.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The **images** are scaled during the process.

You can check more info from OpenCV's doc on [`CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale)'s `scaleFactor` parameter:

> **`scaleFactor`** – Parameter specifying how much the image size is reduced at each image scale.

Comment: Do you know the reason behind this?
It could be much faster if scaling the features.